# QNetworkAccesssManager icinga / nagios acknowledge

Tags: qt, cgi, nagios, icinga

I have a function who sending ack into the icinga / nagios server.

**Function - sendAcknowledge**

```
void MNetworkConnector::sendAcknowledge(QString service, QString host)
{

    QNetworkAccessManager *ackmanager;
    ackmanager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QString ackcommand = "http://nagioscore.demos.nagios.com/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi?cmd_typ=34&cmd_mod=2&host=#host#&service=#service#&com_author=nagiosadmin&com_data=Sent:+mMonitor&btnSubmit=Commit";
    service = service.replace(" ", "+");
    ackcommand = ackcommand.replace("#host#", host).replace("#service#", service);
    connect(ackmanager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished2(QNetworkReply*)));

    QNetworkRequest myReq;
    QUrl myUrl(ackcommand);
    myUrl.setUserName("nagiosadmin");
    myUrl.setPassword("nagiosadmin");
    myReq.setUrl(myUrl);
    myReq.setRawHeader("Referer", "http://nagioscore.demos.nagios.com/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi");
    ackmanager->get(myReq);
}
```

**Function - replyFinished2**

```
void MNetworkConnector::replyFinished2(QNetworkReply *r)
{
    qDebug() << "reply output:" << r->readAll();
}
```

System returned several errors.
If I test this source on my corporate icinga server, I have error:
Not all commands could be send off successfully - Not Authorized

If I test it manualy on my corporate icinga server, I have error: Error: This appears to be a CSRF attack! The command wasn't issued via Classic-UI itself!

If I test it manualy on nagios test site, I have no error. Set service ack is Ok.

If I test this source I have error:Sorry, but you are not authorized to commit the specified command.

What's wrong? Thank you for all your ideas. At first I need solved problem in Icinga, the nagios test page I used only as alternative tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was sensitive to uppercase and lowercase letters in the HOST.

Answer (score 0):

When the website requests authentication `QNetworkAccessManager` will emit the `authenticationRequired()` signal. Try connecting the signal with a slot and then set the username and password on the `QAuthenticator` object passed as argument to the slot.

Connection:

```
connect(ackmanager, SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *, QAuthenticator *)), this, SLOT(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *, QAuthenticator *)));
```

Slot:

```
void MNetworkConnector::authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply *r, QAuthenticator *authenticator)
{
    authenticator->setUser("nagiosadmin");
    authenticator->setPassword("nagiosadmin");
}
```

Comment: This was my first version of code :-). I thought that problem was there so I changed it to verified in QUrl.

Comment: Uhh this is terrible. All problems is only because host name is case sensitive :-(. I transferred all hosts to BIG and then when sending ACK..... grrrrrrrr. 2 days and 2 nigths.

Comment: Oh man! I would tell you I had tested the code you provided and it was working fine. I had imagined the problem was happening for some little detail you didn't notice. I was about to ask you the part of the code where you set the host and service. Hahaha. I'm glad you have fixed the problem despite the time it took.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and effort. Server has really stupid answers. :-). Why don't reports - bad HOST name, HOST not exists or something like this?